# Не разблокируется возможность задавать вопросы

Tags: поддержка, качество-вопроса

Раньше у меня заблокировалась возможность задавать вопросы за какие-то отрицательные вопросы. Репутация у меня была где-то на 200 меньше, чем сейчас. После того как я набрал 200 баллов, я все равно не могу задавать вопросы. Минусов у меня было не больше 10. Это ошибка сайта, или что-то ещё?

> [image]

Ссылка ведёт на страницу справки:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Блокировка автоматическая. Возможно, дело в 40% удалённых вопросов.

Comment: @Qwertiy а где вы это нашли?

Comment: Просто посмотрел список вопросов в профиле. 4 из 10 удалены (870104, 869347, 868471, 776934).

Comment: @Qwertiy киньте ссылку, не могу найти

Comment: @VerNick, я ж тебе id перечислил в скобках.

Comment: @VerNick, а вообще, 3 из 4 доступны в недавно удалённых: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/282637 И ещё 776934.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Система блокирует возможность задавать вопросы, если вы за промежуток времени (обычно это 30 дней) создаете много отрицательного шума. Этот шум высчитывается по формуле, которая включает: количество закрытых вопросов, кол–во удаленных вопросов, количество тревог в ваших вопросах, суммарный рейтинг, минимальный рейтинг и некоторые другие параметры. Как только этот показатель становится ниже заданного значения, система не дает возможность задавать.

Решение: улучшить уже заданные вопросы (вплоть до переписывания [удаленных вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776934/6) с просьбой модераторам восстановить исправленное).

Comment: Но ведь удалённые имеют отрицательный рейтинг. Какой смысл в их восстановлении с точки зрения изменения суммарного вклада? Вообще, странно, что возможности спрашивать и отвечать так развязаны друг с другом. Положительный вклад, имхо, должен оцениваться в комплексе: по вопросам и ответам.

Comment: @alexolut Восстановить можно будет по улучшению, чтобы (1) уменьшить количество удаленных; (2) суммарный рейтинг.

Comment: Следует добавить еще, что "если вы создадите другую учетную запись и будете задавать вопросы с нее, то получите бан за кукловодство"

Comment: @alexolut, как вариант, хочешь задать новый вопрос — редактируешь удаленный бессмысленный "аааааааааааа" и пишешь свой вопрос туда, потом восстанавливаешь его, ну и можно пойти в чатик и попросить снять минусы

Comment: @АндрейNOP, удалённое модератором может восстановить только модератор. Так что можно переписать и в чат за модераторами. Ну или через тревогу.

Comment: @АндрейNOP радикальная смена сути вопроса, насколько я знаю, не приветствуется. Почему тогда замена бессмысленного удаленного аааааааа лучше, чем задание нового вопроса? Меньше записей в БД? Ревизии-то всё равно останутся видны.

Comment: @alexolut, она не лучше, она просто возможность немного улучшить рейтинг по вопросам.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот потому и странно так рассчитывать возможность задавать вопросы. Надо смотреть суммарный вклад (вопросы+ответы). К тому же, даже заминусованный вопрос может породить положительные ответы. Вспоминается знак "реверс". Хорошо это для вклада в сайт (реального, а не какой-то там формулы) или всё таки плохо?

Comment: Мне кажется, что публикация этой формулы в открытый доступ была бы полезной, чтобы возможно было чётко и недвусмысленно видеть, что и как влияет на параметр. Сейчас же мы имеем ситуацию как с поисковыми машинами, закрывающими параметры ранжирования чтобы избежать накрутки SEOшниками. Security through obscurity И страдают от этого как раз добропорядочные участники (плохим проще забросить аккаунт и создать новый)

Comment: @AK, а еще лучше прямо в профиле вывести метрику "качества вклада". Будет тогда еще чем помериться :)

Comment: @alexolut, идея блокировки, в том числе, подразумевает улучшение и восстановление старых вопросов. Улучшить вопрос из букв "а" сохранив его смысл невозможно. Это не рекомендация смысл вопросов менять, а несколько нестандартная ситуация с конкретным вопросом.

Comment: Я не представляю как тот вопрос улучшить. Умолять в чате людей поставить плюсов - тоже бред. Как по мне, не продумана система в этом плане.

Comment: *"Ждать ~месяц"* Хм, а на а основной мете пишут, что [*"Automatic bans never expire or "time out.""*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/353058)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо! Поправил ответ (хотя мне все же кажется, что по времени тоже должен блок сняться).

Comment: Он по времени не снимается, но дает возможность задать еще один вопрос через 6 месяцев (это есть в том же ответе чуть ниже).

Comment: Честно, мой вопрос на который введет ссылка, был проверочным. Я  просто только зарегистрировался :)

Answer (score 5):

Небольшое дополнение. Я задал на MSE вопрос: [Question ban algorithm formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315230/260198)

Формулу вряд ли раскроют, т.к. используя её нарушители будут абьюзить систему.

Предложили использовать вот такой запрос: http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/895607?negdel=0&closedel=0&deleted=0&UserId=282637

Из конкретных рекомендация ничего дельного, по сути. Пишут, что редко кто из бана выбирается.

> Do know only very few people manage to get out of a q-ban. They are
>   mostly considered a lost case.

Comment: Немного еще не понял, на второй ссылке выводит вот такую ерунду: `Q-banned when < 0.5 
------------------- 
null                

(1 row(s) returned)`, что это значит?

Comment: @VerNick если значение меньше 0.5, то, вероятно, последует бан. http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/895607?negdel=0&closedel=0&deleted=0&UserId=282637 У вас 0.5

Comment: Печаль.........

Answer (score 1):

Баллы тут ни при чем, проблема - в удаленных вопросах. Хитрая формула, учитывающая все вопросы включая удаленные, посчитала, что вы не умеете задавать хорошие вопросы, и будет лучше если вы их вовсе перестанете задавать.

Как выйти из бана? Улучшить и восстановить свои старые вопросы, чтобы доказать формуле что вы научились их задавать.

При этом надо помнить, что

1. если вы удалили свой вопрос сами - то и восстановить его можете самостоятельно, если же вопрос был удален модератором - восстановить его может только модератор;
2. если на вопрос не было ответов - его допустимо полностью заменить на другой, если же на вопрос кто-то старался-отвечал - то нельзя менять вопрос делая ответ неверным, это неуважение к другому участнику.

Comment: А если вопрос уже непопулярен и никто его не смотрит, формула ведь его сама не разблокирует?

Comment: @VerNick, после редактирования вопроса, он всплывет и получит свою порцию просмотров

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну хорошо, попробую

Comment: @АндрейNOP к сожалению, эта порция уже далеко не та, что у свежих вопросов.

Comment: @alexolut почему же?

Comment: @PavelMayorov уведомления прилетают только о новых вопросах потому что.

Comment: @alexolut, какие уведомления? На главной вопрос-то всплывет все равно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP те уведомления, на которые люди подписываются через RSS и т.п., чтобы отвечать на вопрос в числе первых и собирать репу. К тому же помимо главной (где всё поднимается) некоторые смотрят исключительно [новые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) по той же причине, что я только что описал.