# Статистика по людям, которые смогли выбраться из бана по вопросам/ответам

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, блокировка, заблокированные-вопросы, статистика

В свете недавнего вопроса: [Не разблокируется возможность задавать вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7787/15479)

И обсуждения на MSE: [Question ban algorithm formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315230/260198)

Интересно было бы посмотреть на статистику того, какой процент "нарушителей" смог выбраться из подобного бана.

Comment: Я за два года постоянного мониторинга нашей русскоязычной меты и чата видел только [одного участника](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7188/213987), который дошёл до меты и ему помогли. Сколько людей блокируется - об этом нужно спрашивать у модсостава/КМ.

Comment: @AK я в чате спрашивал КМ сегодня. Молчком.

Comment: @AK я в понедельник задам на MSE этот вопрос. Думаю, на всех сайтах сети процент людей, который вышли из бана, маленький.

Comment: В общем, задал этот же вопрос на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315304/260198. Интересно, всё же, посмотреть на глобальную статистику, и видят ли они в этом проблему вообще.

Comment: @Suvitruf Судя по тому, за какие вопросы был забанен Ver Nick, система работает правильно.

Comment: @Athari но статистику увидеть всё равно хочется)

Comment: Я смог. После месяца набирания репутации, а потом обращения в чат с просьбой помочь мне, я теперь могу снова задавать вопросы.

Comment: @VerNick ну вот и хорошо)